# How can I pull the latest published revision for a referenced node using the CCK node reference field?

Tags: 6, entities, nodes

Right now if I reference a node in another node via a CCK node reference field, if I change the referenced node, which creates a new revision of that node, it shows the edits on the page that's referencing that node even though I haven't published the latest revision.

I'm looking for a way to patch the node reference field or CCK to join on the node_revision table so it will pull only the latest PUBLISHED version instead of the latest edit.

I have looked through both nodereference.module and content.module under CCK to try to find where the body is pulled in so I can edit the query.  I can't find that query.

Any help is GREATLY appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Which module are you using to get forward-revisions? Revisioning?

This just seems like a bug in node reference field in that it makes the assumption that the latest revision is always published (which is true in core).

http://drupal.org/node/738116 has a patch which seems like it fixes node titles on auto-complete widgets and in the list of nodes. But it falls short of completely fixing the issue.

Comment: Yes, I'm using the revisioning module.  I saw that patch, but yeah, that isn't that useful since the resulting content that is included is the latest edit of the content.